# Conceptual question in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

**Let $H$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G=\{0,a,b,c,...\}$, where $0$ is the identity element in $G$. Then if $H=\{0\}$ then the quotient group $\frac{G}{H}$
is equal to $G$**.

This has occurred in many contexts in my textbook.

Here's what I've done so far - In this case wouldn't it be more correct to say that the quotient group will be like $\frac{G}{H}=\{ \{0\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},....\}$ where $\{0\},\{a\},\{b\},\{c\},....$ are the singleton cosets of the subgroup $H$ in the group $G$ ?

Even if whatever they're writing is right, are they saying that $\frac{G}{H}=G$ because they are isomorphic and in that sense the equality is occurring?
Am I getting it right?

Comment: They are not “equal” in the sense of identical, but they are not merely isomorphic, but canonically isomorphic. So for all intents and purposes, they are “equal”.

Comment: What is the name of your textbook?

Comment: It's Higher Algebra Abstract and Linear by S.K.Mapa

Comment: @Arturo Magidin, with a bit more about "canonically isomorphic", I think your comment worths an answer.

Comment: Yes, you are getting it right.

Comment: I'd love to hear the explanation from those who downvoted this question exactly where my question didn't meet the community guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

This is true.  The groups are, in fact quite trivially, isomorphic.  Map a singleton coset to its representative.

Comment: someone downvoted this question, exactly where my question didn't meet the community guidelines can you tell me?

Comment: Don't worry about it.